# Remove white space from \selectlanguage block

Tags: babel, languages

I'd like to remove the white space (before and after) when I use \selectlanguage{lang}

```
\documentclass[10pt, english, brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\providecommand{\printertitle}{}

\addto\captionsenglish{% ingles
    \renewcommand{\printertitle}{Model of theses and dissertations in LaTeX of the ICMC}%
}
\addto\captionsbrazil{% portugues-brasil
    \renewcommand{\printertitle}{Modelo de teses e dissertações em LaTeX do ICMC}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{resumo}[Abstract]
ANTONELLI, H. L..
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}\printertitle\end{otherlanguage}. 2016. 
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e 
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas 
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.
\end{resumo}

\end{document}
```

This code insert a big white space before and after de text.

For instance:

[image]

Comment: Try with % signs at the end of lines (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines), if this does not help, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I had tried to use % before...
MWE:

 `ANTONELLI, H. L..%
{
\selectlanguage{english}%
\printertitle%
}%
. 2016. 81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.`

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I tried your code fragment with the article class and the babel package, but substitute `\printertitle` by some random text, because I don't know where this command comes from. Unfortunately I can not reproduce your problem. Have you tried with `{%`?

Comment: I updated the code above to comprise the whole .tex file

Comment: Offtopic, but are you sure there should be two periods after the L? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplography

Comment: The two periods is unnecessary.. it's a mistake...

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `otherlanguage` environment.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}

\providecommand{\printertitle}{}

\addto\captionsenglish{% ingles
    \renewcommand{\printertitle}{Model of theses and dissertations in LaTeX of the ICMC}%
}
\addto\captionsbrazil{% portugues-brasil
    \renewcommand{\printertitle}{Modelo de teses e dissertações em LaTeX do ICMC}%
}

\begin{document}

ANTONELLI, H. L..
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}\printertitle\end{otherlanguage}. 2016. 
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e 
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas 
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.

ANTONELLI, H. L..
\printertitle. 2016. 
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e 
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas 
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler method if you just need two languages:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}

\newcommand{\printertitle}{%
  \iflanguage{english}
   {Model of theses and dissertations in LaTeX of the ICMC}%
   {Modelo de teses e dissertações em LaTeX do ICMC}%
}

\begin{document}

ANTONELLI, H. L..
\foreignlanguage{english}{\printertitle}. 2016.
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.

ANTONELLI, H. L..
\printertitle. 2016.
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.

\end{document}
```

Another method, rather flexible, for more than two languages; you do

```
\definelanguagevariable{<command>}
  {
   {<language 1>}{<text 1>}
   {<language 2>}{<text 2>}
   ...
   {<language n>}{<text n>}
```

and then call either `<command>` or `<command>[<language>]`. Without the optional argument the text corresponding to the current language is used; the optional argument will use the stated language.

In the example below, `\printertitle` will print the Portuguese text, `\printertitle[english]` the English text; but `\printertitle` after `\selectlanguage{french} prints the French text.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definelanguagevariable}{mm}
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{o}
   {
    \str_case_x:nn { \IfNoValueTF{##1}{\languagename}{##1} } { #2 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelanguagevariable{\printertitle}
 {
  {brazil}{Modelo de teses e dissertações em \LaTeX{} do ICMC}
  {english}{Model of theses and dissertations in \LaTeX{} of the ICMC}
  {french}{Model pour th\`eses et dissertations en \LaTeX{} de l'ICMC}
 }

\begin{document}

ANTONELLI, H. L..
\printertitle. 2016. 
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e 
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas 
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.

ANTONELLI, H. L..
\printertitle[english]. 2016. 
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e 
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas 
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.

\selectlanguage{french}
ANTONELLI, H. L..
\printertitle. 2016. 
81 p. Tese (Doutorado em Ciências – Ciências de Computação e 
Matemática Computacional) – Instituto de Ciências Matemáticas 
e de Computação (ICMC/USP), São Carlos – SP, 2016.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried the first option (otherlanguage), but the problem is the same... Unfortunately, I don't know why this happened. About the second option, I don't have only two languages. =/

Comment: @HumbertoLidioAntonelli The second example can also be used with more languages, `\newcommand{\printertitle}{%
  \iflanguage{english}{Model of theses and dissertations in LaTeX of the ICMC}{}%
  \iflanguage{french}{bonjour}{}%
  \iflanguage{portuguese}{Modelo de teses e dissertações em LaTeX do ICMC}%
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use \hspace{acm} where a can be negative or positive depending upon whether you want to shrink the space or expand. For example \hspace{-2cm} shrinks the space by 2 cm.

Comment: I can not use absolute measures. The text of the code block is generated dynamically.